# Is there an R function to show significance for two groups by counts?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

Greetings of the day

I am trying to show a monotherapy drug effect from baseline to follow-up changeover within groups by counts. I can't figure out any R function related to this study hypothesis. I am trying to prove that drugs have some effect from baseline to follow-up by counts.

My dataset looks like below

```
Drugs   Baseline    Followup
Drug1         87    99
Drug2          6    9
Drug3         36    29
Drug4         34    43
Drug5          2    4
```

Any suggestions for this hypothesis testing are welcomed in all aspects

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand your question, but what you're describing sounds like a chi square test, e.g.

```
df <- read.table(text = "Drugs   Baseline    Followup
                         Drug1         87    99
                         Drug2          6    9
                         Drug3         36    29
                         Drug4         34    43
                         Drug5          2    4",
           header = TRUE,
           row.names = 1)
 
df
#>       Baseline Followup
#> Drug1       87       99
#> Drug2        6        9
#> Drug3       36       29
#> Drug4       34       43
#> Drug5        2        4

chisq.test(x = df$Baseline, y = df$Followup)
#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#> 
#> data:  df$Baseline and df$Followup
#> X-squared = 20, df = 16, p-value = 0.2202
```

If you are looking for help with statistics, the best place to ask is https://stats.stackexchange.com/